# Bash script to delete folders older than 30 days, but omit 1st and 15th

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, backup

I have a mount where I store my db backups, and to avoid it growing beyond control, I only intend on keeping 30 days worth of backups, but also backups created every 15 days.  So as 30 days expires, if the folder was created on the 1st or 15th, I would like it to stay as well.

I'm currently using this to only keep the backups for 30 days, how can I omit folders created on the 1st and 15th?

```
find /mnt/clusterfs01-data01/db01/* -type d -ctime +30 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Sample directory listing for folder names.

```
0 drwx------ 7 root root 324 Nov 11 01:35 2016-11-11_01-31-41
0 drwx------ 7 root root 250 Nov 11 06:25 2016-11-11_06-25-03
```

I don't mind a solution other than `find`.

Comment: Do your filenames contain the date? Or are you relying on the date stats of the file?

Comment: I was relying on the date but the folder could be acceptable.  I updated the question to include the folder names. @glennjackman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To exclude matches based on the directory name's datetime string, you could add

```
! \( -name '????-15-??*' -o -name '????-30-??*' \)
```

or

```
-not \( -name '????-15-??*' -o -name '????-30-??*' \)
```

to the `find` command.

If you really want to base it on the timestamp, then the only way I can think to do that is something like (**note** I'm using `mtime` here since your `touch` commands don't seem to modify the `ctime` on my system: change `%Td` to `%Cd` for `ctime`):

```
find dir -type d -mtime +30 -printf '%Td\t%p\0' | 
    while read -rd '' day dir; do 
      case "$day" in 
        15|30) ;; 
        *) echo rm -rf -- "$dir";; 
      esac
    done
```

Comment: Steel, +1, but _touch commands don't seem to modify the ctime on my system_ is weird cause `touch` makes the `inode` to change, which should modify the `ctime`. Which FS are you on?

Comment: @heemayl maybe I just copy-pasted it wrong - the dir is ext4 on an SSD that is mounted with `noatime`, if that makes a difference? Otherwise, it's vanilla Ubuntu 12.04 (well, mythbuntu actually)

Comment: I experienced the same thing with the touch commands I had posted.  It seems to leave the Change time but adjusts the access/modify times.  I had to do my testing with mtime assuming the real deal would use ctime.  @heemayl

Comment: The more I thought about it, using the folder name is actually better.  At least on ext4, the `Birth` time is not stored.  The folder name has the timestamp in it, so for instance, 1:31:41 in my first example.  The timstamp on from stat on the folder is 1:35:57.  If the backup ever spanned over the day, that would cause a problem and then be on the 16th instead of the 15th perhaps. @heemayl

Comment: FWIW: I had to redirect the output since it seems to complain about the folder not being there that it's deleting.

Comment: @bc2946088 you may need to add `-depth` to the find command so that it traverses the tree in strict order

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
rm -rf $(find /mnt/clusterfs01-data01/db01/* -maxdepth 0 -type d -ctime +30 | grep -v "[0-9]\{4\}-01\|15-[0-9]\{2\}")
```

Comment: Actually, the grep was just misplaced the date.